# viewport height, whilst centralising the image within slider css

Tags: image, css, viewport, background-size

I have a slider on a homepage I am currently working on. I am trying to achieve a full viewport height that takes up the whole width for the screen.

The only way I can currently achieve this is by either stretching the image, or the image isn't centred.

The image needs to be aligned roughly centred horizontally and vertically, so customers can see the centre of the image on any width of browser, and without stretching the image out of proportion.

I have tried the background-size: cover; on the element with no success as its not a background img. the containers have 100vh currently, but the width is the issue.

The issue is located here http://joeybox.info/ . I realise with the menu and the logo above the image the 100 viewport height will rest under the "fold", however I am placing the logo and menu over the image eventually, once I have figured out the css.

I have tried many solutions found within the stack overflow forum and none work in my scenario.

My current css, after deleting the in-correct code, is:-

```
.bx-wrapper img {display: inherit;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: inherit;}

.ewic-wid-imgs {height: 100vh;
    max-width: unset;
    width: unset;}

.bx-wrapper img {display: inherit;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: inherit;}
```

html=

```
<div class="slider-box">
    <div id="ewic-con-385">
    <div style="display: none;" id="preloader-385" class="sliderpreloader">
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 100%; margin: 0px auto;" class="bx-wrapper">
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 633px;" class="bx-viewport">
    <ul style="width: 315%; position: relative; left: 0px;" class="bxslider-385">
    <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 1349px; margin-right: 10px;" class="ewic-slider bx-clone">
    <img title="Qw Direct Leather Keyrings" class="ewic-wid-imgs" src="http://joeybox.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/qw-direct-leather-keyrings.jpg">
    <div class="ewic-caption"><span>Qw Direct Leather Keyrings</span></div>
    </li><li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 1349px; margin-right: 10px;" class="ewic-slider">
    <img title="Qw Direct Leather Keyrings" class="ewic-wid-imgs" src="http://joeybox.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/qw-direct-leather-keyrings.jpg">
    <div class="ewic-caption"><span>Qw Direct Leather Keyrings</span>
    </div></li><li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 1349px; margin-right: 10px;" class="ewic-slider bx-clone">
    <img title="Qw Direct Leather Keyrings" class="ewic-wid-imgs" src="http://joeybox.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/qw-direct-leather-keyrings.jpg"><div class="ewic-caption">
    <span>Qw Direct Leather Keyrings</span>
    </div></li></ul></div>
    <div class="bx-controls bx-has-controls-direction bx-has-controls-auto">
    <div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev disabled" href="">Prev</a>
    <a class="bx-next disabled" href="">Next</a></div><div class="bx-controls-auto"><div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-start active" href="">Start</a></div>
    <div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-stop" href="">Stop</a></div></div></div></div><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add some more html?

Comment: Please take that code and [edit] into your question.

Comment: Added to original question

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could add to your image inside .bx-wraper:

```
.bx-wrapper img {
  display: inherit;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

now you need to set the parent `li` to relative:

```
.bx-wrapper ul li {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

and change your parent ul:

```
.bx-wrapper ul{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not fill the whole width, or centres the image on smaller browser widths.

Comment: Could you give me a link of the current situation?

Comment: Could you add the above css to the current link? So we can work from there?

Comment: I will add it for now so you can see how 1) the image isnt centred, and 2) not full viewport size e.g. height:100vh;

Comment: I have added the css now so you can see. .

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above by changing my image slider. My new slider plugin (Envoke Supersized) uses a background image and was easier to use background-size:cover; css. Although after this full viewport height on mobile widths didn't look good with my images so I used 40vh on mobile widths.

I would recommend anyone trying to do the same to ensure your image is a background image, or replace the slider with a static background image for small browser widths.